# SQL Server client statistics result is way off

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, statistics

I have just analyzed a call to a particular SQL Server Stored Procedure. It is very slow so I decided to analyze it.

The result is confusing:

1. When executing the procedure it takes 1 min 24s.
2. When executing two identical calls simultaneously it takes 2 min 50 s. Obviously some bad blocking and context swapping is happening.
3. When switching on Actual Execution Plan and running one call it takes 4 min 48s. The client statistics now tells me the total execution time is 3000ms.

What is happening?

Does the Actual Execution Plan actually interfere that much?

That means there should be a warning somewhere that the execution time is MUCH longer and the statistics is WAY off.

The procedure is not huge in size but with a nasty complexity: cursors, nested selects in five levels, temporary tables, sub procedures and function calls.

Comment: We later found out we had problems with the test database. In Azure we exported a bacpac file that was restored to our test database. From some reason the restore was not complete. The indexes were not enabled after restore!!! That obviously gave very strange results on all test runs.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of articles in the web discussing why using cursors is a bad practice and should be avoided when possible. Depending on database settings a cursor is registered in the global namespace making concurrency close to impossible - it is absolutely normal that 2 instances of your proc take exactly twice longer. Performance of cursors and locking are another points of consideration. So having said that even a while loop on, say, temp table with identity column to loop on, might be a better solution than cursors.

My experience is that turning on actual execution plan always adds some time - I have noticed that the more complex the plan is the bigger the effect it is (so i guess it is quite related to the SSMS handling it) ... but in your case the effect looks of larger scale than I would expect, so there might be something else going on.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input.

Comment: Now I realize I should be careful with times reported when using Actual Execution Plan. I also really would like to remove all cursors in legacy code, but it is a huge job: 100 Functions and 600 Stored Procedures ... :(